# Как добавить в path папку со всеми подпапками?

Tags: cmd, файловая-система, path

Начав использовать командную строку для запуска консольных приложений, я обнаружил, что команда `start имя_файла` находит и запускает только программы в папках, входящих в переменную среду PATH.

Я разобрался, как добавить папку в PATH, чтобы команда `start находила и запускала находящиеся в ней файлы, но это происходит только если файлы находятся именно в папке, а не подпапках.

Как научить программу `start` искать не только файлы находящиеся именно в папке, но и во всех её подпапках?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого в переменную `PATH` добавьте что то вроде этого:

```
.\node_modules\.bin;..\node_modules\.bin;..\..\node_modules\.bin
```

обычно три уровня вложенности достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте корневую папку c:\Имя_папки и должны задействоваться все подпапки и файлы в данном каталоге.

Comment: Автор написал же: `... но это происходит только если файлы находятся именно в папке, а не подпапках`.

Comment: С чего бы должно?